# Return button "ID" within Iframe

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that let me return a Button "ID" once i click it.

```
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>

<button id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B2</button>

<button id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function reply_click(clicked_id)

{
alert(clicked_id);

}

</script>
```

Can i use the script within an Iframe src container just below the html tag so i can return a clicked button ID within it?

Or should i refer to other means like PostMessage so i'll able to receive a string of the clicked button "ID" and use it later?

Appreciate your help, but i'm a poor graphic designer and new to javascript.

Comment: I am not sure, but I'm am guessing this is not possible due to security reasons. Even if it were possible, it is certainly not recommended.

Comment: Pages in an iframe cannot use Javascript functions defined in the main page, you need to use `PostMessage`.

Comment: @barmar and in case i used postmessage what will the parameter name i should pass through postmessage?